# How to use selector in CustomName command

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I summon an armor stand and gave him tag of `Any`. Now I want to use CustomName command like `/entitydata @e[tag=Any] {CustomName:"Hello player"}` but I want to specify the name of the player using selector using `@p` I was wondering if anyone could help me with it.

Comment: Probably impossible.

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no way to have "dynamic" NBT like that. Unless you set up a different command for every possible name, there is no way to insert a player's name into NBT data.

Comment: so is there any way I can use scorebord value in the CustomName?

Comment: No. You can't insert anything into a custom name; not names, not scores, not NBT, nothing. It can only be the text you typed out beforehand.

Comment: Well thanks for helping me I didn't had this information.Thank you very much.